# How use iOS 7 font?

Tags: ios5, uifont, ios7

We want use iOS 7 font in iOS 5+ app.

We try this:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Ultra Light" size:50];
```

Or

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Neue-Ultra-Light" size:50];
```

But font is **(null)**.

So, how use iOS 7 font?

Comment: If the font isn't included in iOS 5 then you need to find an outside source for the `ttf` file and add it to your application. There are plenty of existing questions here on adding custom fonts.

Comment: use it on iOS 7?  Then font won't be "**(null)**".

Comment: Check iosfonts.com for the exact name to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [iosfonts.com](http://iosfonts.com), you want:

HelveticaNeue-UltraLight

Comment: @omz You beat me by seconds fixing the URL. Thanks.